# DB2 loses track of table after getting 3 levels deep into a subquery

Tags: db2, subquery

With this standard authors/books setup:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE books (
    id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    author_id int NOT NULL,
    sold int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO authors VALUES (1, 'author 1')
INSERT INTO authors VALUES (2, 'author 2')

INSERT INTO books VALUES (1, 'book 1', 1, 10)
INSERT INTO books VALUES (2, 'book 2', 1, 5)
INSERT INTO books VALUES (3, 'book 3', 2, 7)
```

this query somehow doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    books.name
                FROM
                    books
                WHERE
                    books.author_id = authors.id
                    AND books.sold > (
                        SELECT
                            avg(sold)
                        FROM
                            books
                        WHERE
                            books.author_id <> authors.id
                    )
            ) AS t
    ) AS good_selling_books
FROM
    authors
WHERE
    authors.id = 1
```

The error message is:

> SQL0204N  "AUTHORS.ID" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704

It looks like DB2 loses track of the outermost table after getting 3 levels deep into a subquery?

NOTE: This is just a fabricated query so it may not make much sense (and can be easily rewritten to only have 2 levels nesting which works fine). I just want to confirm if DB2 indeed has such a glaring shortcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution which is rather simple. DB2 has this `LATERAL` keyword which is needed for such query to work, e.g.

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            LATERAL( -- this is the only change
                SELECT
                    books.name
                FROM
                    books
                WHERE
                    books.author_id = authors.id
                    AND books.sold > (
                        SELECT
                            avg(sold)
                        FROM
                            books
                        WHERE
                            books.author_id <> authors.id
                    )
            ) AS t
    ) AS good_selling_books
FROM
    authors
WHERE
    authors.id = 1
```

The solution came from this blog post https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/scoping_rules_in_db2125?lang=en, where the author also noticed the same shortcoming in DB2:

> But DB2 also didn't jump two levels up to S.c1. I suppose it could but, alas, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the innermost query.
You can't just compare to authors.id without having authors in the FROM clause.

Comment: +1 The poster has his scoping mixed up. Subselect are standalone statements whose result gets exposed to the outer select not the other way around.

Comment: @Eddy thank you for pointing this out more explicitly than I did.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would the 2nd innermost authors.id work then? By the way, the query works perfectly fine in PostgreSQL and SQL Server.

Comment: It is true that the 2nd innermost reference to authors has the same problem.

Comment: My bad. You are correct about that. However, the scoping point made by Eddy is still fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This also fails in MySQL with the exact same error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'authors.id' in 'where clause'
```

I would suspect that the query is indeed incorrect.  I believe that you need a reference to the `authors` table in the `FROM` clause on the innermost query.  I've been doing a lot of NOSQL stuff lately so my SQL query skills are a little dusty, but I'm pretty sure that an inner query cannot reach *out* to other tables.

Rewrite the query using joins instead of nested queries if you can.  The performance of nested queries tend to optimize poorly anyway (unsubstantiated in DB2, but true in MySQL 5.1 at least).

Comment: I am actually quite surprise that the query doesn't work in MySQL. FYI, it works fine in PostgreSQL and SQL Server. Anyway, the part about "an inner query cannot reach out to other tables" is definitely wrong. Query such as `SELECT a.key, (SELECT count(*) FROM b WHERE b.key = a.key) AS count FROM a` works fine in any database.